# pivot_longer syntax equivalent to reshape::melt

Tags: r, tidyr

This seems trivial. How can I use pivot_longer in place of melt here:

```
foo <- matrix(1:9,3,3)
reshape2::melt(foo,varnames = c("x","y"),value.name = "z")
```

Comment: `pivot_longer` needs a data.frame, and the row needs to be made implicit, and the column names converted to numbers, so: `as.data.frame(foo) |> mutate(x = row_number()) |> pivot_longer(-x, cols_vary = "slowest", names_transform = parse_number)`

Comment: related (not identical): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75228268/tidyverse-analog-of-reshape2melt-that-does-everything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be honest, `tidyr` just doesn't allow this particular operation on matrices as easily as `reshape2::melt` did. I think base R might be more succinct:

```r
cbind(expand.grid(x = seq(ncol(foo)), y = seq(nrow(foo))), z = c(foo))
#>   x y z
#> 1 1 1 1
#> 2 2 1 2
#> 3 3 1 3
#> 4 1 2 4
#> 5 2 2 5
#> 6 3 2 6
#> 7 1 3 7
#> 8 2 3 8
#> 9 3 3 9
```

Comment: Or even data.frame(x = c(row(foo)), y = c(col(foo)), z = c(foo))

Answer (score 4):

You need to transform your data into a dataframe:

```
data.frame(foo) %>%
  rowid_to_column(var = 'x')%>%
  pivot_longer(-x, names_to = 'y', values_to = 'z',
                   cols_vary = 'fastest',
                   names_transform = parse_number)

    # A tibble: 9 × 3
      x     y     z
  <int> <dbl> <int>
1     1     1     1
2     2     1     2
3     3     1     3
4     1     2     4
5     2     2     5
6     3     2     6
7     1     3     7
8     2     3     8
9     3     3     9
```

---

But why go through that struggle? just maintain your `melt` results:

```
foo |>
  `dimnames<-`( list(x = 1:3, y=1:3)) |>
  as.data.frame.table(responseName = 'z')

  x y z
1 1 1 1
2 2 1 2
3 3 1 3
4 1 2 4
5 2 2 5
6 3 2 6
7 1 3 7
8 2 3 8
9 3 3 9
```